# Neo4j LOAD CSV Application Threads Blocked

Tags: neo4j, graphenedb

I am trying to import about 500,000 lines of data from a CSV file using the `LOAD CSV` command in neo4j.

The data in the csv is organized like this:

```
Artists    |    Feature1    |    Feature2    |    Feature3
```

Each of the columns is filled with  names of music artists, most of who show up more than once in a column. If an artist name shows up in any column, I want there to be a node for that artist. If that artists' name shows up more than once in a column an/or in more than one column, I would  like for there to be one and only one node for that artist.

For each artist, I want to keep track of who they feature and who they feature for. Each row of the csv represents a song. For each song an artist makes (each row of the csv), I'd like to add a `FEATURES` relationship from the artist in the `Artist` column to the artist in the `Features1/2/3` columns.

Here is the code I am using:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:Artist) ASSERT a.artistName IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 50
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'https://aws.bigfile.csv' as line
MERGE (artist:Artist {artistName: line.Artist})
MERGE (feature1:Artist {artistName: line.Feature1})
MERGE (feature2:Artist {artistName: line.Feature2})
MERGE (feature3:Artist {artistName: line.Feature3})

MERGE (artist)-[f1:FEATURES]->(feature1) 
ON CREATE SET f1.strength = 1
ON MATCH SET f1.strength = f1.strength + 1

MERGE (artist)-[f2:FEATURES]->(feature2) 
ON CREATE SET f2.strength = 1
ON MATCH SET f2.strength = f2.strength + 1

MERGE (artist)-[f3:FEATURES]->(feature3) 
ON CREATE SET f3.strength = 1
ON MATCH SET f3.strength = f3.strength + 1
```

Desired behavior: the first occurrence of someone featuring another artist creates the `FEATURES` relationship and should set the `strength` property of the `FEATURES` relationship equal to 1. For every subsequent occurrence, the strength property goes up by 1. Therefore, an artist A who frequently features an artist B should have a relationship like `(a)-[:FEATURES {strength: AHighNumber]->(b)`

Relationships are directional and direction matters in this case (A featuring B is different than B featuring A).

There should be over 10,000 distinct artists and therefore nodes, but around 2,000 nodes I start getting issues with system timeout.

I am getting a bunch of the following message in the logs:

```
2017-12-30 10:54:04.268+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.c.MonitorGc] GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 467ms.
```

Is there any other information that may be useful in determining the issue? Any idea how I could restructure my code to avoid this issue? All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paste the query (don't run it, just paste it) into the browser, you'll get a warning on the side, which, when expended, reads:

> The execution plan for this query contains the Eager operator, which
>   forces all dependent data to be materialized in main memory before
>   proceeding.
>   Using LOAD CSV with a large data set in a query where the
>   execution plan contains the Eager operator could potentially consume a
>   lot of memory and is likely to not perform well. See the Neo4j Manual
>   entry on the Eager operator for more information and hints on how
>   problems could be avoided.

That explains why you're seeing performance issues...it effectively cancels out any use of periodic commit.

You can get eager operations in the query plan when you have multiple MERGEs on the same node label. The general approach to getting around this kind of issue is to spend a pass merging in just the nodes from a single variable in the CSV:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 50
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'https://aws.bigfile.csv' as line
MERGE (artist:Artist {artistName: line.Artist})
```

If `line.Artist` in your CSV has all possible artists, then a single pass should work. However if there are other artists in `line.Feature1` (and the others) that aren't in `line.Artist`, then you'll need to do another pass for each one in turn until all your nodes are loaded (you can also push PERIODIC COMMIT up to 5000 to 10000 or so).

Note that your multiple MERGEs of the same relationship type to multiple nodes is also contributing to the EAGER operation. You should really see if you can get your CSV in a different format. You don't really need all those extra columns, `line.Artist` and `line.Feature` should be enough, and then you'll have multiple rows with the same artist and a different Feature, and you won't get caught up with eager operations.

Your alternative, to avoid the eager operations and allow usage of periodic commit, is to to execute the query (after you've imported all your nodes) in 3 passes:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'https://aws.bigfile.csv' as line
match (artist:Artist {artistName: line.Artist})
match (feature:Artist {artistName: line.Feature1})

MERGE (artist)-[f:FEATURES]->(feature1) 
ON CREATE SET f.strength = 1
ON MATCH SET f.strength = f.strength + 1
```

Then repeat but for `line.Feature2` and `line.Feature3`.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out an (intermediate) solution that does not directly address the memory problems above, but works nonetheless.

Previously, I was trying to create the artists nodes from the original file, merging them so that each artists has one and only one node. I suspect the creating/merging of nodes was getting expensive, since for every row of the file cypher essentially has to look through all of the existing nodes to see whether or not to create a new node for that row.

Instead, I wrote some Python code that gets unique values (artist names) for each column, combines them into one long list, and again gets the unique values from this list to filter out duplicate artists that appear in more than one column. I then wrote this to a file with a single column of artists. I used this much shorter file to create all the artist nodes. The code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('artists-full.csv', encoding = 'latin1')
columns = ['Artist', 'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

# Get an array of strings for each column. Clean out repeats
artists_set1 = df.loc[:, 'Artist'].unique().tolist()
artists_set2 = df.loc[:, 'Feature1'].unique().tolist()
artists_set3 = df.loc[:, 'Feature2'].unique().tolist()
artists_set4 = df.loc[:, 'Feature3'].unique().tolist()

# Combine the artists from different columns
artists_list = [artists_set1, artists_set2, artists_set3, artists_set4]
flat_artists_list = [item for sublist in artists_list for item in sublist]
# Get rid of duplicates by creating a set
artists_set = set(flat_artists_list)
# Turn the set back into a list
artists = list(artists_set)
print(len(artists))

# Write the list to csv
with open ('artists.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for artist in artists:
        f.write(str(artist) + '\n')
```

From there, I created the relationships between the artists using the original file and the following Cypher code:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:Artist) ASSERT a.artistName IS UNIQUE;
MERGE (artist)-[f1:FEATURES]->(feature1) 
ON CREATE SET f1.strength = 1
ON MATCH SET f1.strength = f1.strength + 1

MERGE (artist)-[f2:FEATURES]->(feature2) 
ON CREATE SET f2.strength = 1
ON MATCH SET f2.strength = f2.strength + 1

MERGE (artist)-[f3:FEATURES]->(feature3) 
ON CREATE SET f3.strength = 1
ON MATCH SET f3.strength = f3.strength + 1
```